# Twitter.requestCredential function response

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, meteor

What is the expected response from Twitter.requestCredential function? I have my twitter app configured in accouns.js like this:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
service: 'twitter'
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'twitter',
    consumerKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
```

And then I run function like this:

```
Twitter.requestCredential(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

And after all app Authorize process is successfully finished I keep getting these odd strings "5H7he8sfijie1jccrLnBB4oVTdPa-kogKctNpHyQ-18"

I read in the documentation that if I need just OAuth token from Twitter I can use "twitter" package. https://www.meteor.com/accounts

So the question is how do I get real OAuth token from this function?

Comment: First off, where are you getting this `Twitter.requestCredential` function? And what are YOU expecting to get from this? I can't seem to find this function anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I also wasn't able find this function in any documentation.. In fact I wasn't able to find any documentation for this Twitter object at all. This function can be found in twitter.js after twitter package is added via meteor. I'm expecting this function to return me a valid oauth token for twitter user. Just as documentation says. And this is the only function in that file.

Answer (score 0):

`Twitter.requestCredential` can be found in the Meteor codebase on GitHub:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/89971d6205dfbe1d8620b88868fb8c65784daaf5/packages/twitter/twitter_client.js

According to the comments for this function, it calls the callback function `credentialRequestCompleteCallback` on completion. `credentialRequestCompleteCallback` takes one argument: `credentialToken` on success, or `Error` on error.

The `credentialToken` string `Twitter.requestCredential` sends to `credentialRequestCompleteCallback`is just a randomly-generated alphanumeric string appended to the OAuth URL to uniquely identify the login request.

The real work of `Twitter.requestCredential` is being done by `OAuth.launchLogin`:

```
  OAuth.launchLogin({
    loginService: "twitter",
    loginStyle: loginStyle,
    loginUrl: loginUrl,
    credentialRequestCompleteCallback: credentialRequestCompleteCallback,
    credentialToken: credentialToken
  });
```