# Meteor retrieve Twitter credentials

Tags: meteor

I currently have a Meteor application with a custom login (email/password). I am planning on asking users to link their Twitter accounts (multiple Twitter accounts per user if available), so that I can make API requests on their behalf (get tweets, post tweets, search tweets, etc.)

I believe to do this, I need the user's oauth_token, and oauth_secret.

I am using Tim Haines' 'twitter' package to try to implement this. I am also using the following resources: 
[Twitter.requestCredential function response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849292/twitter-requestcredential-function-response)
https://github.com/timhaines/test-accounts/blob/master/test-accounts.js

I am able to pull up the login dialog, enter the Twitter username/password, and I get a token string, which is different with each login attempt. So I know that `Twitter.requestCredential()` is working. However, when I pass the token to the line in the code `Twitter.retrieveCredential(token)`, it returns nothing (undefined).

Here is my client-side code (straight from the link above):

```
            Twitter.requestCredential(function(tokenOrError) {
            if(tokenOrError && tokenOrError instanceof Error) {
                console.log('Error:' + tokenOrError);
            } else {
                Meteor.call('retrieveTwitterCredential', tokenOrError, function(error, result) {
                    if(error)
                        console.log(error.reason);
                    else {
                        console.log('DEMO ONLY - DON\'T send unfiltered credentials to the client on a production app');
                        console.log('Result:', result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

And here is my server-side code (straight from the link above):

```
        console.log(token);
    credential = Twitter.retrieveCredential(token);
    console.log(credential);
        if(credential instanceof Error)
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, credential.message);
        else
            return credential;
```

The 'credential' seems to be undefined. I've been pulling my hair over this for the last two weeks, so if anyone can help, that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this, so I wanted to post it just in case anyone else is having the same issue.

When you make a Meteor method call INSIDE an async function, you need to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment()` to wrap up the callback and use the result of the function in the Meteor method.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
Twitter.get('statuses', id, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response) {
                    // handle the error
                } else {
                    //do stuff with the response
                } 
}, function() { console.log('Failed to bind environment'); }));
```

P.s. this is not just for Twitter auth, but for ANY async function. I had to use Meteor.bindEnvironment() to store the result from an async function which I needed to write to the database by making a Meteor method call. It worked for that as well.

Hope this helps someone in need!