# Meteor retrieve Twitter credentials returning undefined

Tags: meteor, oauth

I'm trying to use the Twitter package to retrieve credentials for a user. The client receives the temporary token just fine, but when I use it to retrieve the real credentials, I get undefined. My code is very simple.

```
// Client
Twitter.requestCredential(function (tokenOrError) {
    Meteor.call('register', tokenOrError)
}

// Server
Meteor.methods({
    register: function(token) {
       var result = Twitter.retrieveCredential(token);
       console.log(result); // undefined
    }
})
```

When I look in my mongo database, the pending credentials have correctly been stored in meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials and the key that was returned to the client is correct. When I do the same query in the database it returns the result just fine, but calling retrieveCredential from the server does not.

Any thoughts?

Links to the OAuth code:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/oauth/pending_credentials.js
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/oauth/oauth_server.js
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/twitter/twitter_server.js

---

My problem is similar to others that have already been asked ([Meteor retrieve Twitter credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644252/meteor-retrieve-twitter-credentials)) but the posted solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the API has changed and requires you to retrieve the credential secret on the client and send both the credential secret and token to the server.

```
// Client
Twitter.requestCredential(function (tokenOrError) {
    var secret = Package.oauth.OAuth._retrieveCredentialSecret(tokenOrError)
    Meteor.call('register', tokenOrError, secret)
}

// Server
Meteor.methods({
    register: function(token, secret) {
       var result = Twitter.retrieveCredential(token, secret);
       console.log(result);
    }
})
```

[How can I get the credential secret in Meteor, when I do Facebook.requestCredential on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428130/how-can-i-get-the-credential-secret-in-meteor-when-i-do-facebook-requestcredent)